# App state, and actions not mapping to props with redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

Unable to access redux store state/app state and actions via props using  `mapStateToPorps`, `mapDispatchToProps`, and `redux connect()`. Calling `this.props.action()` (where `action()` is any action creator), I get an error saying

> **action is not defined**.

I'm struggling to see where the problem is here. Any help here will be greatly appreciated.

**App.js**

```js
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import * as allCommentActions from '../actions/commentActions';
import * as allPostActions from  '../actions/postActions';
import * as allUserActions from '../actions/userActions';

import Main from './Main';

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
      //this.props.posts etc
      posts: state.posts,
      comments: state.comments,
      user: state.user
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({...allUserActions, ...allPostActions, ...allCommentActions}, dispatch);
}



const App = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main);

export default App;
```

**Main.js**

```js
import React from 'react';

export default class Main extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {React.cloneElement({...this.props}.children, {...this.props})}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**store.js**

```js
import { createStore } from 'redux';

import rootReducer from './reducers/index';

let user = {
    isLoading: false,
    awaitingEmailVerification: false,
    isAuthenticated: false,
    user: null,
    preliminaryInfo: null,
    authMessage: null,
    authError: null
};

let posts = {
    loadingPosts: false,
    loadingSinglePost: false,
    removingPost: false,
    addingPost: false,
    updatingPost: false,
    loadedPosts: [],
    serverMessage: null,
    serverError: null,
    curPostId: null,
    curPost: null,
    deletedId: null,
    updatedId: null,
    singleViewPost: null
};

let comments = {
    loadingComments: false,
    removingComment: false,
    updatingComment: false,
    addingComment: false,
    serverMessage:  null,
    serverError: null,
    postComments: [],
    curComment: null,
    deletedId: null,
    updatedId: null,
    votedId: null,
    curVotes: null,
    postId: null
};

const defaultState = {
    user,
    posts,
    comments
};


const store = createStore(rootReducer, defaultState, window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__());


export default store;
```

***index.js***

```js
import React from 'react';

import { render } from 'react-dom';

import App from  './components/App';

// import pages
import Landing from './components/pages/Landing';
import Register from './components/pages/Register';
import Login from './components/pages/Login';


// router dependencies
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';


const router = (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            {/* <div> */}
                <Route path="/" component={App}>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Landing}></Route>
                    <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}></Route>
                    <Route exact path="/register" component={Register}></Route>
                </Route>
            {/* </div> */}
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
)

render(router, document.getElementById('root'));
```

[image: React dev tools info on Provider component]

[image: React dev tools info on App.js component]

Comment: Can you provide a code sandbox example?

Answer (score 0):

**I've found a temporary solution.**

Instead of connecting the redux store to the outer most component, and using React.cloneElement to "pass down" props, namely:

**App.js**

```
const App = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main);

export default App;
```

**Main.js**

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Main extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {React.cloneElement({...this.props}.children, {...this.props})}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**index.js**

```
const router = (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            {/* <div> */}
                <Route path="/" component={App}>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Landing}></Route>
                    <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}></Route>
                    <Route exact path="/register" component={Register}></Route>
                </Route>
            {/* </div> */}
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
)

render(router, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Instead, I just connect the store to the relevant components individually:

**Register.js**

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        user: state.user
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        actions: {
            userActions: bindActionCreators(allUserActions, dispatch),
        }
    };
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Register);
```

**While this works, I'm still looking for a cleaner implementation, preferably my initial idea of connecting the store to an outer most component (Main) via App.js, and using React.cloneElement to pass down state, and action creators as props. Again, any help is greatly appreciated.**